# How to prevent WebView reload after the TabBar change in Xamarin.Forms.Shell app on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, webview, tabbar, xamarin.forms.shell

I work on a `Xamarin.Forms.Shell` app containing 4 tabs. One of these tabs contains a `WebView` allowing users to plane an appointment through an URL given by a provider.

The `AppShell.xaml` looks like this (all the icons are set with `FontImageSource`):

```
<TabBar x:Name="appTabBar">
    <ShellContent x:Name="tabBarHome" Title="Home" Route="HomePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="News" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewsPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Booking" Route="BookingPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:BookingPage}" >
        <ShellContent.Icon>
            <FontImageSource Glyph="{StaticResource FalIconCalendar}" FontFamily="FontAwesomeLight" />
        </ShellContent.Icon>
    </ShellContent>
    <ShellContent Title="About" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
</TabBar>
```

The `BookingPage` looks like this:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>                
        <ctrl:CustomWebView x:Name="webView"
                            Source="{Binding UrlBooking}"                                 
                            WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000"
                            IsVisible="{Binding ShowWebView}">
    </Grid
</ContentPage.Content>
```

When the `BookingPage` is displayed the first time, the `WebView` is loading as expected. However, if the user changes tab and returns to the `BookingPage` there are 2 behaviors depending to the platform:

- On **iOS**, we keep the `WebView` as it was before to changing tab.
- On **Android**, the `WebView` is **reloaded**.

I would like to know if there is a way to prevent the `WebView` reload on Android?

I've already searched on similar topics like [How to prevent webview reload after the tab bar selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59563110/how-to-prevent-webview-reload-after-the-tab-bar-selection) but there was no answer.

Comment: Now there seems to be no way out, there are already similar [reports](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9073) here.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem possible to manage this.

Comment: Maybe there will be an update later.